# Problems SSH-ing into Mac OS X from Internet with port forwarding setup on a Comcast Arris TG862

Tags: macos, networking, mac, ssh, router

I would like to SSH into my Mac from the internet.  Here are some details:

- **Public IP:** 64.xx.xx.xx
- **Mac’s Internal IP:** 10.0.0.10

I have set up port forwarding in my [Comcast Arris TG862](http://www.surfboard.com/products/tg862/) gateway as the following

- **service name:** mac
- **server IP:** 10.0.0.10
- **start port:** 8031
- **end port:** 8031

Remote Login is also enabled in the Mac’s Sharing prefs. And says the following:

> To Log into this computer remotely, type "ssh user@10.0.0.10"

Which works when using another device on the LAN, but does not work when I do:

```
ssh -p 8031 user@64.xx.xx.xx
```

On a device connecting from an external IP.

Any advice would be helpful!

Comment: `ssh` usually runs on port 22, why are you forwarding to 8031?

Comment: doing 'ssh user @64.xx.xx.xx' or ssh -p 22 user@64.xx.xx.xx' does not work when connecting to the mac from external IP.

I have set up ssh port forwarding for a number of guest VMs hosted on the mac using a combination of router port forwarding and additions to VM's config files and doing 'ssh -p <VMportnumber> user@64.xx.xx.xx' has worked fine from external IP however I have not been able to get this working when attempting to connect to the host itself

Comment: That is the kind of pertinent information that should be [edited into the question](http://superuser.com/posts/963184/edit); as it may affect things and it's not immediately apparent why you are forwarding to 8031.

Comment: Have you configred `ssh` on your Mac to listen on port 8031?

Comment: issue resolved: i forwarded the preferred port in the router, enabled upnp and zero config

downloaded portmaps for mac and routed local ssh to the public port.  thank you for responding!

Comment: please, describe your solution in the answer field down there to help other people and remove this question from "unanswered".

Answer (score 1):

**Issue Resolved:** I forwarded/targeted the preferred port in the router, enabled upnp and zero config in theComcast Arris TG862 gateway, downloaded port maps for mac and routed local SSH to the public port. Thank you for responding!